# Template KendoUI variable Json ${ } to variable php

Tags: php, html, kendo-ui

My datasource with json brings me the name of a file that is in $ {filename} want this pass it to a php variable.

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
    <div class="product">
        <?php 
            $filename = "${filename}";
            echo $imgSrc = $RUTA_IMG_SMALL . $filename;
            $imgBinary = fread(fopen($imgSrc, "r"), filesize($imgSrc));
            $imgStr = base64_encode($imgBinary);
        ?>
        <a href="vista_producto.php?codigo_producto=${codigo_producto}&codigo_sublinea=<?php echo $_GET["codigo_sublinea"]?>&nicename=<?php echo $_GET["nicename"]?>&codigo_grupo=<?php echo $_GET["codigo_grupo"]?>&sublinea=<?php echo $_GET["sublinea"]?>&codigo_sublinea=<?php echo $_GET["codigo_sublinea"]?>" target="_self">
            <?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.$imgStr.'" />';?>        
        </a>
        <h3>${nombre}</h3>
        <p>${codigo_producto}</p>
    </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kendo expressions such as #= # , ${} are executed on the **client** which makes it impossible to create server variable from it.